# WPF .Navigating Stack Overflow

Tags: wpf, navigation, frame, stack-overflow

I am trying to check if a user is logged in before allowing navigation to any pages, if not it will redirect to the login page. I'm working this all inside a frame element.

The current code creates an infinite loop if the user is not logged in. Can I call it and also pass the event handler a code that tells it to ignore .navigate for this one line?

```
public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            FrameWindow.Navigating+=FrameWindow_Navigating;
        }

        private void FrameWindow_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) {
            try {
                if (UserLoggedIn()) {
                    //continue 
                }
                else {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    FrameWindow.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing this... not sure if this is against any conventions or not?

```
private void FrameWindow_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) {
            try {
                bool alreadyHeadingToHome = false;

                if (e.ExtraData != null){
                    alreadyHeadingToHome = (bool)e.ExtraData;
                }

                if (UserLoggedIn() || alreadyHeadingToHome) {
                }
                else {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    FrameWindow.NavigationService.Navigate(uri, true);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```